# When I run the Android App in Android Studio, these errors occurs

Tags: android-studio

When I run the Android App in Android Studio, these errors occurs (see the attachment). The emulator appears. But there I cannot see the application written by me. How to fix this? I haven't created any app using Android Studio before. I'm using it on Windows 8.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKnoh.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

1. Try starting Android Studio as an Administrator
2. Depending on the target android version you want to compile with, you might want to lower your JDK to 1.7.
3. If you're already running JDK 1.7, try reinstalling JRE and JDK